# Does "n" key have some special meaning in Lua tables?

Tags: c++, lua, associative-array

http://lua-users.org/wiki/CppLuaDataPassing has this code to create a Lua table from C++:

```
   // set first element "1" to value 45
   lua_pushnumber( state, 1 );
   lua_pushnumber( state, 45 );
   lua_rawset( state, -3 );

   // set the number of elements (index to the last array element)
   lua_pushliteral( state, "n" );
   lua_pushnumber( state, 1 );
   lua_rawset( state, -3 );
```

It seems that the last block implies that Lua tables have some special-meaning key of "n" which stores the index to the last array element, based on that example.

But I couldn't find any reference to that in [Lua Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html).

- Is my guess right or wrong?
- If it's right, can someone point me to a good reference explaining this "n" key?
- If wrong, what is the meaning of that second block of code in the example?
- And if it's right, is doing this last index assignment required to create a valid table in  C++ for Lua reading (assume that Lua code will NOT modify the table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be a convention to hold the size of the table. I believe in lua 5.1 they deprecated that as a practice in favor of the `#` operator, as there were times when it would seemingly magically conflict with data people were stuffing in their tables.

Comment: Do I need to set it in 5.2 when pushing onto the table? Thx

Comment: no, not unless you're using legacy scripts that require it be set in your specific application. just use the `#` operator if you're in v5.2+

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://www.lua.org/pil/19.1.html

`n` represents the length of an array. It is most commonly used with `getn()` function, which simply returns the amount of elements in the table.

Comment: That online version of PiL is for Lua 5.0.

Comment: It's basically the same for 5.2

Comment: Hmm, no. The use of `n` is deprecated. `table.getn()` and `table.setn()` do not even exist anymore in 5.2.

Comment: @catwell - Do I need to set it in 5.2 when pushing onto the table? Thx

Comment: Well, not if you don't use it explicitly elsewhere. The only use of `n` is to be able to get the length of the table faster than `#` but usually you don't need it.